# discord python kick and ban command

Tags: discord.py

In Discord.py, we have created a command to banish a user. However, the result is output as Nameerror: name'app' is not definded. This is my code.

Do you have any problems with @app.command?

I use client run instead of app run.

````
@app.command(name="<<kick", pass_context= True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def _kick(ctx, *, username: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await user_name.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(str(user_name) + '\n```User was kick!```')```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you use `client.run` you also have to use `@client.command(...)`.

Comment: Doing so will throw an AttributeError:'Client' object has no attribute'command' error.

Comment: Can you include more of your code then? @studio07

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments, you're using a discord.Client instead of a commands.Bot. If you want to use the commands module, you need to use [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) instead.